# Protractor E2E testing: LoginPage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, protractor, e2e-testing

So, I am trying to test my login page using protractor e2e testing for my ionic app. This is my first time using protractor and I am having trouble understanding the error that I am getting.

> Error:- Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user1"]"}

I'm stuck, i just need guidance. It's my first time testing.

app.e2e-spec.ts:

```
describe('Login tests', () => {

browser.driver.get('http://url.path/login');


it('login page works', function() {
  // Checking the current url
  var currentUrl = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
  expect(currentUrl).toMatch('/login');
});

it('should sign in', function() {


// Find page elements
 var userNameField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));

 var userPassField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password'));
//  var userLoginBtn  = browser.driver.findElement(By.id('loginbtn'));

// Fill input fields
userNameField.sendKeys('nick@email.com');
userPassField.sendKeys('123456');

// Ensure fields contain what we've entered
// expect(userNameField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('nick@email.com');
// expect(userPassField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('123456');

// Click to sign in - waiting for Angular as it is manually bootstrapped.
// userLoginBtn.click();

return browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          return /success/.test(url);
      });
}, 10000);
});
});
```

Login.html:

```
<!--
  Generated template for the LoginPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar transparent>
      <!--ion-title>Login</ion-title-->
    </ion-navbar>

  </ion-header>


  <ion-content padding>

    <div class="align">
        <h1>Atelier</h1>
    </div>

      <ion-card>
          <ion-card-header>
           Login
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
             <ion-list >
               <ion-item>  
                   <ion-input id="username" type="email"      placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
               </ion-item>
               <ion-item>  
                   <ion-input id ="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
               </ion-item>
              <button  ion-button full clear color="light" (click)="login(user)">Login</button>
              <button ion-button block round outline color="light" (click)="register()">Register</button>
             </ion-list>    
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>

  </ion-content>

    <style>
      h1{
        font-size: 3em;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Sacramento;
        font-style: cursive;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
      }
  </style>
```

app.po.ts:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class LoginPage {
 navigateTo(){
  return browser.get('/login');
 }
 get usernameLabel() {
  return element(by.css('.login-field:nth-child(1) label'));
  }

 getEmailTextbox() {
  return element(by.id('username'));
 }
 get passwordLabel() {
  return element(by.css('.login-field:nth-child(2) label'));
  }
getPasswordTextbox() {
 return element(by.id('password'));
  }
  }

   export class Page {

   navigateTo(){
    return browser.get('/login');
      }

    getTitle() {
   return browser.getTitle();
    }

   getPageOneTitleText() {
   return element(by.tagName('page-page1')).element(by.tagName('ion-  title')).element(by.css('.toolbar-title')).getText();
     }

  goToLoginPage(): any{
   let LoginPage = require("../src/pages/login/login").default;
   return new LoginPage();
  }

 getUser(){
   return element(by.id('username'))
 }

  getPass(){
   return element(by.id('password'))
   }

 }
```

Comment: From your given error `"selector":"*[id="user1"]"`,  your script failed to find an web element which `id=user1`, but from your given HTML and test script, nothing hints there is such element.

Comment: Honestly, you have too many problems in your script. Some of them are - try moving `browser.driver.get('http://url.path/login');` in your `it` block. `var currentUrl = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();` returns a promise, not a value. `browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));` looks like webdriver syntax. and in any case, your script fails because of `[id="user1"]` element, which is not mentioned in your spec or PO

Comment: and I personally tend to write everything in spec file, verify each command one by one and then move out whatever is needed to PO

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error fro Protractor

> Error:- Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user1"]"}

and you are using this locator that is not possible because you are using `id= username` and your protractor return "selector":"*[id="user1"]"
 that is not believable.

```
 var userNameField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username'));

 var userPassField = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password'));
```

you are using protractor then you must user protractor locator protractor provides the awesome locator class then you must use protractors locators.

you can use `element(by.model('user.email'))` that is best suitable for your test.